# Save photos to Android Gallery

Tags: android, save, android-gallery

I try to add a `Bitmap` photo that I took with the phone to the gallery in Android Studio but I am getting the error:

```
Failed to insert image
   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=4110, uid=10058 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

I have used in the Manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="21"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
```

The way I save the image is:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), FullBitmap, "Name" , "Date");
```

I am using the Nexus 5 emulator and Android version 5.1.

Comment: Are you sure it is Android 5.1, not 6.0? because only starting from Marshmallow, you can deny permissions individually

Comment: `android:maxSdkVersion="21"` why? your device is API 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @njzk2 pointed out, do not use the [`android:maxSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) attribute. This attribute is meant for permissions that are no longer necessary for higher API levels. The example given in the documentation is one of the few reasons you should apply this attribute:

> For example, beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer
>   necessary for your app to request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
>   permission when your app wants to write to its own
>   application-specific directories on external storage (the directories
>   provided by `getExternalFilesDir()`). However, the permission is
>   required for API level 18 and lower.

In your case, you are accessing a public directory; for which you *do* need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on all API levels.